# How to make a disabled spinner not to look disabled?

Tags: android, spinner

I have made a spinner and when there is only one item on it I want to disable it, but I don't like the grayish look the text gets when it's disabled. I already tried to use `.setClickable(false);` but it did not work. I have seen a lot of posts with the other way around having a disabled one with look different than the default one, but it didn't help me.
My code right now is:

```
if (list.size() > 1) {
    list.setlistNumber("Select a list");
    list.add(0, list);
    mListSpinner.setClickable(true);
    return list;
} else {
    mAccountSpinner.setEnabled(false);
    // mListSpinner.set;
    t = 1;
```

but I have no idea on how to get the Enable(false), look like a Enable(true) without being selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will helpful to you.

In xml

```
           <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And In java:

This is my code, which I tested.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Please select a item");
    list.add("Item1");
    list.add("Item2");
    list.add("Item3");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (list.size() > 1) {
        layout.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        layout.setClickable(true);
    }
```

Comment: tried this one, does not work as the default way the spinner works, makes clickable true even if it is false,(or at least when i tried it didn't work for me)

Comment: I have updated the java code, which I tested. See above

Comment: I don't know if its my computer but I am unable to make in work, but if someone else tells me work for them i'll accept this one

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the listener in order not to do anything but keeping the default behaviour.

```
spinner.setOnClickListener(null);
```

If you want to enable the spinner again, just add once again the listener

```
spinner.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Comment: I tried this and got this exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead. i tried also with setOnItemClickListener but get this other exception: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Override with a custom styled background with no disabled drawable.

```
   <Spinner
      ...
      android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
      ...
   />
```

res/drawable/spinner_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- changed from apptheme_spinner_disabled_holo_light -->
<item android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_default_holo_light" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_default_holo_light" />
```

The drawables will depend on the style of your app. You can generate new holo style drawables [here](http://android-holo-colors.com/) for example.

As for the text colour, this should be very similar, adding a similar xml descriptor:-

```
   <Spinner
      ...
      android:textColor="@color/spinner_text"
      ...
   />
```

res/values/spinner_text.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/black"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/black" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/black" />
   <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

not even sure if that is needed, you may be able to set the color directly:

```
       <Spinner
      ...
      android:textColor="#000000"
      ...
   />
```

Comment: can you elaborate this some more? otherwise I think it should be a comment, also I am not really good at android but the issue is not the background but the text, will this fix that?

Comment: yeah meant to add detail when I had a moment and that never happened. this should stop the text and background from changing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```